# Prove a set is a subset of some complete residue system mod $p$. $p$ is an odd prime.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for all odd prime p, the set R = {$r^{2}$ | 0 $\leq$ r $<$ $p/2$} is a subset of some complete residue system mod p.

This is the first time I've encountered a problem like this, and I have guessed and checked for the complete residue system for hours already.  Is there some theorem that I am missing that can determine a complete residue system given a subset?

Edit: My thought process was, if I can provide an example of a complete residue system containing elements of R, then I would be good to go.  So I created some sets such as R' = {$r^{2}$ | 0 $\leq$ r $\leq$ p}.

But R' is not a complete residue system because although R' has p elements, the elements are not congruent modulo p.  For example, for p = 7, R' = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36} and $4\equiv25\,mod\,7$

So I spent a long time coming up with sets when it dawned on me there probably is some technicality to the question I am not getting.

Edit: I don't have up-vote privileges yet but thanks for all the answers.  I got some more clarification on the question and indeed I can see why the wording is confusing because it confused me as well.  The question was basically asking could R be a subset of some arbitrary complete residue system mod p.  A property of a complete residue system mod p is that two distinct elements must not be congruent modulo p, so any subset of that set must also have this property.  So the answers provided provides that justification.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add details in your post about what and how you guessed and checked for hours.  Please add those efforts in your post, and also please articulate where you get stuck, and what specifically has you confused. As is, your post is likely to be closed and downvoted.  So I encourage you to improve it.

Comment: Hello, I made an edit in the post.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure what the problem actually is.

I guess that it is about proving that $0=0^2$, $1=1^2$, ..., $k^2$ are distinct modulo $p$ if $k$ is the greatest integer less than $\frac12p$.

So let $0\leq r<s<\frac12p$ two integers and assume that $r^2\equiv s^2\bmod p$.
This happens exactly when $p\mid s^2-r^2$.

But $p$ is prime so $p\mid s^2-r^2=(s+r)(s-r)$ implies that either $p$ divides $s-r$ or $s+r$.

I leave to you the task of proving that given the range of $r$ and $s$ both this possibilities are excluded, reaching a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is poorly stated but is probably asking you to show that no two members of $R$ are congruent modulo $p$. I suggest a proof by contradiction: suppose that $0\le r<s<\frac{p}2$ and $r^2\equiv s^2\pmod p$, and try to get a contradiction. Recall that the assumption that $r^2\equiv s^2\pmod p$ just means that $p\mid s^2-r^2$. You may find it useful to factor $s^2-r^2$, and you will definitely need the hypothesis that $p$ is prime.